# DateTime conversion between different culture info

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I want to create different conversion between countries and i am using c#.
I am trying to convert a date time to another date time, format dd-mmm-yyyy.

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language.US); //en-us
DateTime dateStart= DateTime.ParseExact(myDate.ToString(),"dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm:ss tt", ci); //mydate: 12/01/2013 17:00:00 a.m.
```

And it gives error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
Please advice.

Comment: What is the value of myDate.ToString()?

Comment: the value is commented on second line. //mydate: 12/01/2013 17:00:00 a.m.

Comment: You need to give format only in two cases 1. When converting Date to String  2. When converting String To DateTime. The thing you are trying to do is not the either case.Since you are converting mydate to dateStart and both are of type DateTime...

Answer (score 2):

**1.** your String Should contain `AM` or `PM` but not `a.m` or `p.m`
**2.** your current `Date String -> 12/01/2013 17:00:00 a.m.` is Wrong as it contains `a.m` for 17th Hour.it should be -> `12/01/2013 17:00:00 PM`
**3.**  you can use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as `CutureInfo` to deal with different `Cultures`.
**4.**  if your Month is 3 letter word like JAN, FEB, DEC. etc., you can use `MMM` insted of `MM` as month custom format.
like this ->`"dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"`

**Solution 1:**
Try This: if your Month is Two Digit number

```
String myDate = "11/01/2013 17:00:00 PM";
DateTime dateStart = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

***Solution 2:***
Try This: if your Month is Three Letter Word

```
String myDate = "11/DEC/2013 17:00:00 PM";
DateTime dateStart = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: The format with dd-mmm-yyyy is not supported? (like 1-DEC-2013) ?

Comment: @user2483797: yes it supports shall i edit my answer?

Comment: i asked because it gives error with the "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt" format. The purpose is get it 1-dec-2013..

Comment: @user2483797 : now check my edited answer with section `Solution2` if your month is like `DEC`.

Comment: The ulgy part is that for a current Culture like french, the result will be the translation in french for month..MMM and not the english.

Answer (score 0):

You are Parsing the string value of myDate using the given date format, use `myDate.[ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)("dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm:ss tt") to convert a date to a string format.

Comment: Looks like the format is not correct. It gives: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown word starting at index 3.