# How to convert a DateTime to a relevant string for other region than current system?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a problem with converting time to different formats when I have for example a date
"30.07.2021 08:34:53" and I want to convert it to the correct format on another device on which it takes what format it uses and accordingly converts it e.g. to the American one that is MM/DD/YYYYY which would give "07.30.2021 08:34".

My code:

```
    string date = "30.07.2021 12:20:05";
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureinfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");

    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date, cultureinfo);
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Day + " " + dt.Month + " " + dt.Year);
```

I get this error:

```
[System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Program.Main() :line 10
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime.Now Date Format and Windows Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867594/) and [How can I get date and time formats based on Culture Info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353232/) and [c# converting datetime in a different culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165642/) and [How to convert DateTime in different System culture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126433/) and [DateTime conversion between different culture info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327806/)

Comment: You may want to look at [the documentation for `DateTime.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_). Notice that the `IFormatProvider` (which `CultureInfo` implements) argument corresponds to the culture information of the input, not the output. (DateTime itself really has no "formatting", it's only when you convert it back to a string that the output format is used.)

Comment: *the American one that is MM/DD/YYYYY which would give "07.30.2021 08:34".* - careful, there is no `DD` or `YYYY` specifier; there is `dd` and `yyyy` - case matters: `MM` is months, `mm` is minutes` (months are big, minutes are small). Also `MM/dd/yyyy` would give `07/30/2021`, not `07.30.2021 08:34`. You need to be a lot more precise with this data conversion malarkey

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format of the input date, ParseExact it

```
string date = "30.07.2021 12:20:05";

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

If you want to then output in the format of the local system, you can with little effort:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Any time you turn it to a string (as is done here implicitly by passing it to `WriteLine`, which ultimately causes `ToString()` to be called on it), it will use the culture settings of the thread that executes the `ToString()` which, unless specific efforts have been made to change it, will be derived from the regional settings of the system the program is running on

Answer (score -1):

When parsing a date that is formed differently than usual, or US standards, you need to specify the correct culture.

The first culture with a MDY display date on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) page is Italy.

Checking [Microsoft's Supported Culture page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/common-parameters-and-types/supported-culture-codes) shows Italy has the country code of `it`.

Thus your code can be fixed as follows:

```cs
string date = "30.07.2021 12:20:05";
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureinfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("it");

DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date, cultureinfo);
Console.WriteLine(dt.Day + " " + dt.Month + " " + dt.Year);
```